# qwidget background image not showing on other computers

Tags: qt, dll, qwidget

After successfully making an installer for a qt application, I realize background images on qwidets doesn't show when installed on different computers although they do show on my own computer. I'm sure it has to be with dynamic libraries but i just don't know how to go about it. I need help please.

Comment: are the images correctly bundled? (as in the locations are not specific to your computer)

Comment: i compiled the images using the qresource compiler

Comment: What type of images are these? Maybe you're missing some plugins?

Comment: they are .png and .jpg images

Comment: .png images should work, but for .jpg images you will need to add a plugin to your app. You have to copy `qjpeg.dll` from the `imageformats` directory located in something like `C:\Qt\5.1.0\mingw48_32\plugins\imageformats`. You put this .dll file in a subdir called `imageformats` that is located in the directory that contains your deployed .exe file.

Answer (score 1):

> You have to copy qjpeg.dll from the imageformats directory located in something like C:\Qt\5.1.0\mingw48_32\plugins\imageformats. You put this .dll file in a subdir called imageformats that is located in the directory that contains your deployed .exe file

This worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is missing image plugins. You need to read about how to [deploy a Qt application on windows](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html).